# Eclipse plugin trying to load icon from a deleted plugin project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

At first I had created the Helloworld plugin using the Eclipse new project wizard. I was able to successfully run it.Then I deleted that project (checked "Delete contents on disk" as well).

After that I created a **View contribution using 4.x API** plugin project.
While running the plugin, the below message was displayed

```
!MESSAGE Removing PartDescriptorImpl with the "viewplugin.views.SampleView" id and the "Sample View" label.It points to the non available "bundleclass://org.eclipse.ui.workbench/org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView" class. Bundle might have been uninstalled
```

But a new eclipse window is opened and when I try to open the view, an exception was thrown and the contents of the view were not displayed.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.runtime 4 0 2021-04-02 16:08:38.367
!MESSAGE Invalid input url:platform:/plugin/Helloworld/icons/Sample.png
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "Helloworld".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.FindSupport.find(FindSupport.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.find(FileLocator.java:206)
```

and

```
!MESSAGE The image could not be loaded: URLImageDescriptor(platform:/plugin/Helloworld/icons/Sample.png)
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jface.resource.DeviceResourceException: Unable to create resource URLImageDescriptor(platform:/plugin/Helloworld/icons/Sample.png)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createResource(ImageDescriptor.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.DeviceResourceManager.allocate(DeviceResourceManager.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jface.resource.AbstractResourceManager.create(AbstractResourceManager.java:88)
```

(haven't pasted the full stack trace)

The location mentioned in the stack trace is that of the deleted Helloworld project. Why is eclipse trying to load the icon from a previous project?

I tried restarting the workspace, also tried creating a new workspace. But the error is still generated.

**NOTE** : I haven't made any changes to the template plugin. Also, there are no issues with hello world template project

Comment: Try running with the `-clean` option

Comment: @greg-449 In the program arguments right? The exception is still thrown.
`URI: bundleclass://Helloworld/com.plugins.helloworld.parts.HelloWorldView`

Comment: Yes, in the Run Configuration Program Arguments. I usually have `-consoleLog -debug -clean`

Comment: @greg-449, the issue was with the default location of the workspace data in the launch configuration which was `${workspace_loc}/../runtime-EclipseApplication`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the location specified under the workspace data is `${workspace_loc}/../runtime-EclipseApplication`. This somehow was causing the previous project to be loaded as well.
[image]

I was able to fix this by following these steps:

1. Click on `Workspace` option under the "Workspace Data" in the Launch configuration.
2. Select the appropriate plugin project.
3. Apply and Run/Debug.